# Page isn't working - too many redirects

Tags: google-chrome, internet, redirection

I am trying to access a particular website (www.mixcloud.com). On my laptop, for some reason I get an error:

> This page isn’t working 
>   www.mixcloud.com redirected you too many times. 
>   Try clearing your cookies. 
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've tried with different browsers like Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer, also trying incognito mode to make sure it is not an issue of cookies.  I keep getting this error.  All other websites seem to work fine.

If I try on my Android phone, it works fine.  This is using the same Wifi connection.  I find it hard to believe that this is an issue from Mixcloud itself, given this has been going for quite a while and I couldn't find other users complaining of the same issue.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cookies on that device?

Answer (score 0):

here's a couple ideas that can help
- restart your dns, open up cmd or whatever, type in `ipconfig /flushdns`

- delete all your cookies, use [ccleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) for this or clean all your browsing data via your browser, eg. chrome or firefox
- try using another browser
- install an extension to block tracking cookies and whatnot, potentially something from the website could be redirecting you back and forth to something else
  you can enable this in firefox's settings